# Map point to closest point on fibonacci lattice

Tags: python, math, 3d, coordinates, reverse

I use the following code to generate the [fibonacci lattice, see page 4](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.4540.pdf) for the unit sphere. I think the code is working correctly. Next, I have a list of points (specified by latitude and longitude in radians, just as the generated fibonacci lattice points). For each of the points I want to find the index of the closest point on the fibonacci lattice. I.e. I have `latitude` and `longitude` and want to get `i`. How would I do this?

I specifically **don't want to iterate over all the points from the lattice** and find the one with minimal distance, as in practice I generate much more than just `50` points and I don't want the runtime to be `O(n*m)` if `O(m)` is possible.

**FWIW, when talking about distance, I mean [haversine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import math
import sys

n = 50
phi = (math.sqrt(5.0) + 1.0) / 2.0
phi_inv = phi - 1.0
ga = 2.0 * phi_inv * math.pi

for i in xrange(-n, n + 1):
    longitude = ga * i
    longitude = (longitude % phi) - phi if longitude < 0 else longitude % phi
    latitude = math.asin(2.0 * float(i) / (2.0 * n + 1.0))
    print("{}-th point: ".format(i + n + 1))
    print("\tLongitude is {}".format(longitude))
    print("\tLatitude is {}".format(latitude))

// Given latitude and longitude of point A, determine index i of point which is closest to A
// ???
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is a spatial index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index. Since you only care about nearest neighbor search, you might want to use something relatively simple like http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html.

Note that spatial indexes usually consider points on a plane rather than a sphere. To adapt it to your situation, you'll probably want to split up the sphere into several regions that can be approximated by rectangles. You can then find several of the nearest neighbors according to the rectangular approximation and compute their actual haversine distances to identify the true nearest neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat easier to use spherical coordinates here.

Your spherical coordinates are given by lat = arcsin(2 * i / (2 * N + 1)), and lon = 2 * PI * i / the golden ratio.
Reversing this is not a dead end - it's a great way to determine latitude. The issue with the reverse approach is only that it fails to represent longitude.

sin(lat) = 2 * i / (2 * N + 1)

i = (2 * N + 1) * sin(lat) / 2

This i is an exact representation of the index of a point matching the latitude of your input point. The next step is your choice - brute force, or choosing a different spiral.

The Fibonacci spiral is great at covering a sphere, but one of its properties is that it does not preserve locality between consecutive indices. Thus, if you want to find the closest points, you have to search a wide range - it is difficult to even estimate bounds for this search. Brute force is expensive. However, this is already a significant improvement over the original problem of checking every point - if you like, you can threshhold your results and bound your search in any way you like and get approximately accurate results. If you want to accomplish this in a more deterministic way, though, you'll have to dig deeper.

My solution to this problem looks a bit like this (and apologies, this is written in C# not Python)

```
    // Take a stored index on a spiral on a sphere and convert it to a normal vector
    public Vector3 UI2N(uint i)
    {
        double h = -1 + 2 * (i/n);
        double phi = math.acos(h);
        double theta = sqnpi*phi;
        return new Vector3((float)(math.cos(theta) * math.sin(phi)), (float)math.cos(phi), (float)(math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi)));
    }

    // Take a normalized vector and return the closest matching index on a spiral on a sphere
    public uint N2UI(Vector3 v)
    {
        double iT = sqnpi * math.acos(v.y); // theta calculated to match latitude
        double vT = math.atan2(v.z, v.x);   // theta calculated to match longitude
        double iTR = (iT - vT + math.PI_DBL)%(twoPi); // Remainder from iTR, preserving the coarse number of turns
        double nT = iT - iTR + math.PI_DBL; // new theta, containing info from both
        return (uint)math.round(n * (math.cos(nT / sqnpi) + 1) / 2);
    }
```

Where n is the spiral's resolution, and sqnpi is sqrt(n * PI).
This is not the most efficient possible implementation, nor is it particularly clear. However, it is a middle ground where I can attempt to explain it.
The spiral I am using is one I found here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20121103201321/http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/browse_thread/thread/983105fb1ced42c/e803d9e3e9ba3d23#e803d9e3e9ba3d23%22%22

(Orion's spiral is basically the one I'm using here)

From this I can reverse the function to get both a coarse and a fine measure of Theta (distance along the spiral), and combine them to find the best-fitting index. The way this works is that iT is cumulative, but vT is periodic. vT is a more correct measure of the longitude, but iT is a more correct measure of latitude.

I strongly encourage that anyone reading this try things other than what I'm doing with my code, as I know that it can be improved from here - that's what I did, and I would do well to do more. Using doubles is absolutely necessary here with the current implementation - otherwise too much information would be lost, particularly with the trig functions and the conversion to uint.